# Quartz.Net jobs not always running, 1.2

Tags: quartz.net

i have a problem with the older version 1.2 that it miss jobs
and i found MisfireInstruction property that i can change to ignore the time draft but i don't know if it in milliseconds or seconds or what.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with 2.x myself but it should be the same or at least similar for 1.2.  The misfire instruction tells the scheduler how to behave when dealing with misfired triggers, you can set it to various options, firing now, ignoring misfires, scheduling the next execution with existing count and so on. A misfire is established based on the misfire threshold which is usually in ms and defaults to 60000 ms. You can increase the misfire threshold to a large value so that triggers have time to execute without being labelled as misfired. That was my solution in combination with using the fire now misfire instruction. I increased the threshold as well since I found that misfired triggers wouldn't execute sometimes.

Comment: the problem that i can't find most of this options in 1.2, only the MisfireInstruction and i don't know if it will in milliseconds or not. so i came up with 
trigger.MisfireInstruction = trigger.MisfireInstruction * 5
the problem if the default is zero